# Reading http file on url

Tags: java, xml, http, url

I am trying to read an xml file on an http url. "Unexpected end of file from server" keeps on coming . the page is password protected, I would like to know if I am properly giving in my url authentication details.

I tried with non protected pages and I can read them properly. Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://username:pass@0.0.0.0:0000/test.xml");
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:769)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:766)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)

Comment: And I just realize on my wireshark that username being sent is empty :username =""